# Exception Handling in Dask (Float Conversion)

Tags: python, exception, dataframe, dask

I'm trying to do exception handling with my dask dataframe when converting values to floats. Basically I want to convert each value to a float and if it throws an exception set it to None. Currently I have the following function:

```
def float_apply(x):
    try:
        return float(x)
    except Exception:
        return np.NaN
```

I then do:

```
datall = datall.applymap(float_apply).compute()
```

However my exception is not being caught and a ValueError is simply being returned. Is there a way to do this with dask?

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect that the ValueError you're getting is from `compute()` not from `float_apply`. Does `compute` know how to deal with `None`s ?

Comment: I believe the value error is coming from float_apply because it is spitting out an error for converting 'k' to a float when run.

Comment: If you'll try to run this function separately you'll see that it doesn't.

Comment: Is there a way to deal with this then? I thought compute would simply evaluate the new dataframe...

Comment: `float()` can indeed cause a `TypeError`

Comment: I try to catch a general exception (Exception) and it still is returning:

ValueError: could not convert string to float: K

Comment: You maybe should define the `meta` in applymap, because the column you get out is no longer float, as it contains objects (`None`). Alternatively, supply a `float('nan')` instead of `None`.

Comment: I've switched to to return np.NaN but still same issue

Comment: @user48944 I recommend that you create an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question.   This will make it much easier for other people to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The way I got around this was to cast everything as an object and then convert to floats.